# Postman behavior different than HTTP plugin for PHP

Tags: php, json, http

I want to send a HTTP post request to my node.js server. I pass a JSON object as body (content type is set to application/json).

If I send -exactly- the same JSON object in the body via Postman (https://www.getpostman.com) it works perfectly! If I use this plugin here: https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-php it is not working, I get HTTP error 500 and error message 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined' like something would be wrong with my route/ my passed JSON.. which is definitely not the case because Postman works.

How can I fix this? Is there maybe a better PHP plugin that works as it should?

I hope somebody can help me.

```js
//HTTP Requests an Node Server. Pfade entsprechend abändern sobald live
 $teamsMemberOf = Unirest\Request::get("http://localhost:3001/members-matter/mm-teams/".$result['_id']."/get-teams");
 $json = $teamsMemberOf->raw_body;
 
 $buildJson = '{"team":'.$json.'}';
 //$sendJsonEncoded = json_decode($buildJson, true);
 
 $headers = array("Accept" => "application/json");
 
 $relevantBoxesAmount = Unirest\Request::post("http://localhost:3001/members-matter/mm-boxes/".$result['_id']."/get-relevant-boxes-amount", $headers, $buildJson);
 //$relevantBoxesAmount = Unirest\Request::post("http://mockbin.com/echo?", $headers, $buildJson);
 //$relevantBoxesAmount = Unirest\Request::post("http://localhost:3001/members-matter/mm-boxes/56954133596dc02d0695cb89/get-relevant-boxes-amount", $headers, $sendJsonEncoded);
 echo $relevantBoxesAmount->code;
 echo $relevantBoxesAmount->raw_body;
```

Comment: Why you don't use cURL library? I know nothing about "postman" plugin, but I recommend using standard solution (cURL).

Comment: Consider using curl, but anyway if you have a Server side problem (500) then include at least the errors from server log, and if possible also the relevant code portions from the server too